# Not able to push an apk to system/app on rooted Nexus 10 tablet

Tags: apk, adb, android

I need to push an apk to system/app (I need my apk to work as system app). I am using nexus 10 tablet (4.4.2 - Kitkat). I have rooted the tablet.

When I try to push the apk using adb, it show "failed to copy - Read only file system"

I also tried to remount the /system with read write permission, still I am getting same error.

After remounting, I changed the permission of system and app folder to "777". Still I get the same error.

Can someone tell me how can I make it to work.

Comment: Did you also updated package.xml and package.list ?

Comment: @Robert .. No I did not do that. Can you please tell what exactly I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

1. adb shell
2. mount -o rw,remount /system
3. go to /system/app and  remove your_app.apk if available
4. exit from shell
5. adb pull /data/system/packages.xml – this will download file to current directory on your PC
6. adb pull /data/system/packages.list
7. remove  tag with attribute name= your_app_package (and all its content) from packages.xml  and entry in packages.list
8. upload files using adb push command
9. clear dalvik cache using adb shell rm /data/dalvik-cache/*
10. remove your_app_package from a data folder using adb shell rm -r /data/data/your_app_package
11. reboot phone using adb reboot after restart you will be able to install new app

Some of this point can be omitted - please try

Hope will help

Comment: Thanks for your solution. When I try step 5, it gives me permission denied error.

Comment: are you have connected one device? are you able to go to that location with adb?

Comment: I changed the permissions of those file on device. Now I am able to pull them. Will go ahead with further steps

Comment: I could execute all the steps mentioned in your answer. Still I get the same error.

Comment: When you go to adb shell are you as root@android ?

Comment: When I go it is not #(root). It is $ (user mode). But then I am able to do "su" and get into #(root) mode.

Comment: so I guess that is the problem maybe you have rooted it in a wrong way. I have root@android

Comment: Probably you may be correct. For now atleast I can do +1 for your answer. And after testing if, I could root it properly and it works, then I can accept your answer as well.